# Magento product page resize

Tags: magento

http://dev.factorydirectmedical.com/wheelchairs?mode=grid this is my product page and I want to resize the images. I used Magento developer option to hint the template path. Here a screenshot, (http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/1645297/4998c8379ebab36e77cab59c1a9c3bd5), I found the HTML file but I'm unable to fix this image box.

**List.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     be
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010-2015 MeigeeTeam. (http://www.meigeeteam.com)
 */
?>
<?php
/**
 * Product list template
 *
 * @see Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List
 */
?>
<?php
    $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
    $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
    $meigeeOptions = $this->getLayout();
    $gridColumns = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('listing_columns');
    $productType = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('listing_product_type');
    $listType = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('listing_list_type');
    $grid_indents = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('listing_indents');
?>
<?php if(!$_productCollection->count()): ?>
<p class="note-msg"><?php echo $this->__('There are no products matching the selection.') ?></p>
<?php else: ?>
<div class="category-products">
    <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    <?php // List mode ?>
    <?php if($this->getMode()!='grid'): ?>

    <ol class="products-list" id="products-list">
    <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setProductInfo($_product)->setProductList($this)->setIterator($this)->setTemplate($listType)->toHtml(); ?>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ol>
    <script type="text/javascript">decorateList('products-list', 'none-recursive')</script>
    <?php else: ?>
    <?php // Grid Mode ?>

    <ul class="products-grid row <?php echo $gridColumns.''.($grid_indents != 1 ? ' no-indents' : ''); ?>">
        <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setProductInfo($_product)->setProductList($this)->setTemplate($productType)->toHtml(); ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
     </ul>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        decorateGeneric($$('ul.products-grid'), ['odd','even','first','last']);
    </script>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <div class="toolbar-bottom">
        <?php echo $this->getToolbarHtml() ?>
    </div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(window).load(function(){
            function buttonsSize(){
                if(jQuery('.category-products li.item').length){
                    jQuery('.category-products li.item').each(function(){
                        itemsCount = jQuery(this).find('.image-box .actions').children().length;
                        switch(itemsCount) {
                            case 1:
                                itemsCountClass = 'one-item';
                            break;
                            case 2:
                                itemsCountClass = 'two-items';
                            break;
                            case 3:
                                itemsCountClass = 'three-items';
                            break;
                            case 4:
                                itemsCountClass = 'four-items';
                            break;
                            default:
                                itemsCountClass = 'four-items';
                            break;
                        }
                        jQuery(this).find('.image-box .actions').addClass(itemsCountClass);
                    });
                }
            }
            buttonsSize();
            jQuery(window).resize(function(){
                buttonsSize();
            });
            if('undefined' != typeof GeneralToolbar) {
                buttonsSize();
            }
            GeneralToolbar.onInit = function(){
                buttonsSize();
            }
        });
    </script>

    <?php if(Mage::app()->getLayout()->getBlock('ajaxkit')->issetSubmodulesConfig('general_toolbar')) { ?>
        <div class="infinite-scroll-elements">
            <div class="infinite-scroll-loader"><div></div></div>
            <div class="infinite-scroll-button" id="StaticScrollBtn"><?php echo $this->__('Show More Products'); ?></div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php
// Provides a block where additional page components may be attached, primarily good for in-page JavaScript
if ($this->getChild('after')){
    $_afterChildren = $this->getChild('after')->getSortedChildren();
    foreach ($_afterChildren as $_afterChildName){
        $_afterChild = $this->getChild('after')->getChild($_afterChildName);
        //set product collection on after blocks
        $_afterChild->setProductCollection($_productCollection);
        echo $_afterChild->toHtml();
    }
}
?>
```

**new.phtml**

```
<?php
/**
 * @package     be
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2010-2015 MeigeeTeam. (http://www.meigeeteam.com)
 */
 $meigeeOptions = $this->getLayout();
 $lightBox = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('lightbox_listing');
 $timerStatus = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('timer_status');
 $timerListingStatus = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('timer_listing_status');
 $catalogModeWrapper = $meigeeOptions->getMConfigResultByAlias('catalog_mode');
 $catalogMode = $catalogModeWrapper['value']['sv2']['value'];
?>
<?php if (($_products = $this->getProductCollection()) && $_products->getSize()): ?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="widget widget-new-products clearfix">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <header class="widget-title">
                <h2><?php echo $this->__('New Products') ?></h2>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="widget-products col-xs-12">
            <?php echo $this->getPagerHtml() ?>
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="products-grid clearfix">
                    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_products->getItems() as $_product): ?>
                        <li class="item col-xs-6 col-sm-3">
                            <div class="image-box">
                                <?php if($lightBox){ ?>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductMediaResized(930, 'small_image')->getImageSrc(); ?>" data-toggle="lightbox" class="lightbox-button" data-footer="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Lightbox'); ?>">
                                        <i class="icon-search"></i>
                                    </a>
                                <?php } ?>
                                <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setProductInfo($_product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/product_labels.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>" class="product-image">
                                    <span class="mask"></span>
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $_product->productHoverImage($this, 800); 
                                        $escaped_label = $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true);
                                        echo '<img '. $_product->getProductMediaResized(800, 'small_image')
                                            ->addImageHtmlAttributte('alt', $escaped_label)
                                            ->addImageHtmlAttributte('title', $escaped_label)
                                            ->getImageHtmlAttributte().' />';
                                    ?>
                                </a>
                                <div class="actions clearfix">
                                    <?php if ($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                        <?php if($catalogMode == 0) { ?>
                                            <button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')); ?>" class="btn btn-default pull-left" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_product) ?>')"><span><span><i class="icon-basket"></i></span></span></button>
                                        <?php } ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <a class="btn btn-default" href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Read More')); ?>"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                                        <span class="link-wishlist-wrapper"><a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_product) ?>" class="link-wishlist" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist'); ?>"><i class="icon-heart-fa"></i></a></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                    <?php if($_compareUrl=$this->getAddToCompareUrl($_product)): ?>
                                        <span class="link-compare-wrapper"><a href="<?php echo $_compareUrl ?>" class="link-compare" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Compare'); ?>"><i class="icon-shuffle"></i></a></span>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>)"><?php echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName() , 'name') ?></a></h3>
                            <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                                <p class="availability in-stock"><i class="icon-record"></i><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php else: ?>
                                <p class="availability out-of-stock"><i class="icon-record"></i><?php echo $this->__('Product') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true, '-new') ?>
                            <?php if($timerStatus && $timerListingStatus) {
                                echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('catalog/product/listing_timer.phtml')->toHtml();
                            } ?>
                            <hr class="indent-18 white-space"/>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images come from `list.phtml`
There may use other method to get this image. if you unable to find image then please provide me `list.phtml` file code

Comment: please see this , I have update list.phtml code and new.phtml also

Comment: you need to debug this `<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('page/html')->setProductInfo($_product)->setProductList($this)->setTemplate($productType)->toHtml(); ?>`
If you are know magento well then this is very easy.

Comment: you have any Idea about this . where this will be

Comment: in your theme folder check folder `page/html`

Comment: any Other custom option@ I tried to disable list.phtml, form base  package,and also running package. but still product showing page. but i comment line in from catolog.xml for lis.phtml then hide every thing ,

Comment: it fall back effect.

Comment: yes , sunny i solve my problem . thanks for your support man. thanku